# Give value to hidden input onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For design reasons I want to have a `<li>` to click when selecting what to view (post form to view data), so I put some hidden inputs inside of it and I'm wondering if I onclick can give the clicked hidden input a value and then `var getVal = Request.Form["clickedInput"];` get the value on my AJAX page like this, meaning it will send the value on post, because it will post on click also.

But I only want the clicked one to get the value, and if I click another tab in the `<li>` I want the first to then get its value removed and the now clicked input to get a value instead? Make sense?

This is my code for the form including the `<li>`.

```
        <form method="post" action="~/AJAXcalls/repinintAJAX.cshtml" name="form">
            <div class="reportDateDiv">

                <a class="blackColor fSize18 RPtxt">Reporting Period</a>

                <input type="text" name="inputDate" spellcheck="false" class="datepicker metricDateTextbox capitalFirst"
                       onchange="mySubmit(this.form)" value="@inputDate" autocomplete="off" placeholder="@placeholderStartDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy")" readonly="readonly" />

                <a class="blackColor fSize16 RPtxt RPtxtTo">to</a>

                <input type="text" name="endDate" spellcheck="false" class="datepicker metricDateTextbox capitalFirst"
                       onchange="mySubmit(this.form)" value="@endDate" autocomplete="off" placeholder="@noEndDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy")" readonly="readonly" />

                <select name="NormOrAvg" class="dwmViewSelect" onchange="mySubmit(this.form)">
                    <option selected=@(Request.Form["NormOrAvg"] == "1") value="1">Rep Per Set</option>
                    <option selected=@(Request.Form["NormOrAvg"] == "2") value="2">Average Rep Per Set</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="holdLiftMenu">
                <ul class="holdLiftMenuUL">
                    <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
                        <a class="holdLiftMenuA total current">Total
                            <input type="hidden" name="hid4" id="hid4" value="" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
                        <a class="holdLiftMenuA squat">Squat
                            <input type="hidden" name="hid1" id="hid1" value="" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
                        <a class="holdLiftMenuA benchpress">Benchpress
                            <input type="hidden" name="hid2" id="hid2" value="" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
                        <a class="holdLiftMenuA deadlift">Deadlift
                            <input type="hidden" name="hid3" id="hid3" value="" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </form>
```

This is my code that are linked to the `<li>`, so far it just hide/show my divs but I also want the value assign/remove to happen on the same click, if possible?

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".total").click(function () {
                $("#piechart").show();
                $("#piechartS").hide();
                $("#piechartB").hide();
                $("#piechartD").hide();
            });
            $(".squat").click(function () {
                $("#piechart").hide();
                $("#piechartS").show();
                $("#piechartB").hide();
                $("#piechartD").hide();
            });
            $(".benchpress").click(function () {
                $("#piechart").hide();
                $("#piechartS").hide();
                $("#piechartB").show();
                $("#piechartD").hide();
            });
            $(".deadlift").click(function () {
                $("#piechart").hide();
                $("#piechartS").hide();
                $("#piechartB").hide();
                $("#piechartD").show();
            });
        });
```

I'm by no means good at js or jquery but im guessing some changes has to be made to the script code, since at the moment the click function is linked to the a tag classes and not the inputs, but I would like some help here if this is possible.

I use cshtml and its not MVC!

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what it is you're looking to happen. If it's possible, could you be a bit more clear?

Comment: @PontusSvedberg `$("input[name=hid1]").val();` - returns the value `$("input[name=hid1]").val("NewVal");` - sets the new value... If it's what you are looking for

Comment: @zfrisch , my `<li>` has 4 "tabs", each with a hidden input, onclick, give it a value to post, on my ajax page, call this value, ex. 1, so that I can use this in a if statement. but if not clicked, it shouldn't have a value so while called it doesnt get anything, only from the clicked one, does this make more sense?

Comment: @AdamK. ah thats nice! that works for me! u could put it as an answer

Comment: @PontusSvedberg done - Happy coding! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery documentation is your friend here: http://api.jquery.com/val/

val() function can be used these ways:

```
var hiddenvalue = $("input[name=hid1]").val(); // returns input value
$("input[name=hid1]").val("NewVal"); // sets input value
```

Simply put `$("input[name=hid1]").val("NewVal");` at the end of anonymous function triggered by click();

```
$(".total").click(function () {
    $("#piechart").show()
    $("#piechartS").hide();
    $("#piechartB").hide();
    $("#piechartD").hide();
    $("input[name=hid1]").val("NewVal");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to show the text field which you can change it later. Check it out the code which would make your text field active on li click. I hope this helps:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#prentUL li').click(function(){
$('#prentUL li input').val('');
 $(this).find('input').val('active');
});
            
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="~/AJAXcalls/repinintAJAX.cshtml" name="form">
            <div class="reportDateDiv">

                <a class="blackColor fSize18 RPtxt">Reporting Period</a>

                <input type="text" name="inputDate" spellcheck="false" class="datepicker metricDateTextbox capitalFirst"
                       onchange="mySubmit(this.form)" value="@inputDate" autocomplete="off" placeholder="@placeholderStartDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy")" readonly="readonly" />

                <a class="blackColor fSize16 RPtxt RPtxtTo">to</a>

                <input type="text" name="endDate" spellcheck="false" class="datepicker metricDateTextbox capitalFirst"
                       onchange="mySubmit(this.form)" value="@endDate" autocomplete="off" placeholder="@noEndDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy")" readonly="readonly" />

                <select name="NormOrAvg" class="dwmViewSelect" onchange="mySubmit(this.form)">
                    <option selected=@(Request.Form["NormOrAvg"] == "1") value="1">Rep Per Set</option>
                    <option selected=@(Request.Form["NormOrAvg"] == "2") value="2">Average Rep Per Set</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="holdLiftMenu">
                <ul class="holdLiftMenuUL" id="prentUL">
                    <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
                        <a class="holdLiftMenuA total current">Total
                            <input type="text" name="hid4" id="hid4" value="" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
                        <a class="holdLiftMenuA squat">Squat
                            <input type="text" name="hid1" id="hid1" value="" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
                        <a class="holdLiftMenuA benchpress">Benchpress
                            <input type="text" name="hid2" id="hid2" value="" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
                        <a class="holdLiftMenuA deadlift">Deadlift
                            <input type="text" name="hid3" id="hid3" value="" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </form>
```